# Asp.Net Core Custom Authentication Middleware scheme

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

My project has a front-end and an API in the same solution so I am building a custom authentication middleware which is meant to authorize only the API controllers since the Front-end controllers use Identity.

I am setting the AutomaticAuthenticate option false for Identity on Startup.cs like this

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {                
            config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            config.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie";
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticAuthenticate = false;                           
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And for my custom middleware I implemented custom options and I've done this

```
app.UseApiAuthorizationMiddleware(new ApiAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Api",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = false
        });
```

Now when I try to use

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Api")]
```

in my controller Visul Studio tells me that AuthenticationSchemes couldn't be found and I'm missing and assemby or reference. Quick Action tool tells me to add

```
"System.Net.Primitives": "4.0.11-rc2-24027"
```

but I end up with version 4.0.10 and it doesn't compile... I'm not sure if what I'm done so far is good or if indeed there is an issue here.

I hope it's clear.

thanks

Comment: I guess a side question is if that is the way to make Identity not automatic?

Comment: Do you call app.UseApiAuthorizationMiddleware before app.UseIdentity? Does you middleware inherit AuthenticationMiddleware ?

Comment: I call it after and i do inherit from authenticationmiddleware

Answer (score 1):

To properly implement a custom authentication middleware I had to not only implement a middleware that inherits from AuthenticationMiddleware but also implement an authentication handler that extends from AuthenticationHandler and all the logic goes on the method HandleAuthenticateAsync()